# R: Count items in a nested list

Tags: r, list, count, statistics

How do you efficiently count items in a nested list? For example, I have a list of header names such as:

```
header.names <- list(list("Post Unique Reference", "Name", "Grade (or equivalent)", "Job Title", "Date", "Date"), 
     list("Name", "Organisation", "Unit", "Reporting Senior Post", "Grade", "Date"))
```

I'd like to calculate statistics of how many times a header occurs.

A simple approach could be

```
require(stringr)
sum(str_count(unlist(header.names), "Date"))
```

However:

- Counting "Name" should yield 2.
- Counting "Date" should also yield 2 because each list counts once.
- Counting "Grade" should yield 1 - how would a non-exact search look like so it yields 2?

Comment: `table(unlist(lapply(header.names, unique)))`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Zbynek's point:

Since duplicates within each element of the list should be ignored, you need to loop over the list taking unique values .

```
unique_headers <- lapply(header.names, unique)
```

To deal with everything at once, it is easiest to flatten the list, so you can use a vectorised solution.  Since you don't care about the names of the elements, you can get a modest performance boost by passing `use.names = FALSE`.

```
flat_headers <- unlist(unique_headers, use.names = FALSE)
```

Finally you want to count the elements in the list.  Depending upon what output format works best for you, you have a choice of `table` or `count` from `plyr`.

```
table(flat_headers)

library(plyr)
count(flat_headers)
```

Non exact matching is something of an art: you need to have a think about what your data looks like and how fuzzy the matchines are allowed to be, in order to get the answer that you want.

For example, is stripping everything inside parentheses OK for your use case?
Are there examples of header names that differ only by case?
Are there misspelled header names?

Comment: is there a way to sort `count(flat_headers)` in descending order?

Comment: The easiest wy to sort a data frame is with `arrange` in the `plyr` package.  Try `counts <- count(flat_headers); arrange(count, desc(freq))`